# Rails: how do I create form fields for combinations of attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, design-patterns

I have a model with a lot of fields where many of them are closely related.

Say I have the model: `Fruit` with attrs: `fruit_type: ['apple', 'banana']`, `fruit_color: ['red', 'green', 'yellow']`, `is_rotten: ['true', 'false']`.

Now I want to create some super user friendly create/edit forms for these models, where users can edit the attributes. Rails is great for this:

creating a form like:

```
= form_for @fruit do |f|
  = f.select :fruit_type, options_for_select(['apple', 'banana'])
  = f.select :fruit_color, options_for_select(['red', 'green', 'yellow'])
  = f.check_box :is_rotten
  = f.submit "save!"
```

Will give you all the great benefits of rails automatically rendering which value the attribute is currently taking etc. etc. with very limited amount of code.

Now. In reality, if this is gonna be super user-friendly and fast to use, it would be much more meaningful to combine some of these fields, so the user would only have to select one item from a combined list, which would then generate the right data on the model:

```
= form_for @fruit do |f|
  = f.select :fruit_color_and_fruit_type, options_for_select(['Yellow apple', 'Red apple', 'Green apple', 'Yellow banana'])
  = f.check_box :is_rotten
  = f.submit "save!"
```

This however is of cause not supported straight out of rails. So, what pattern(s) could I use to make this play nice with rails' standard ways of doing things (strong params, pre-setting the value in the form, attribute mass assignment etc. etc.), so I don't have to hack and hardcode everything everywhere?

Comment: Because you know in which order the data is shown to the user, just split the string in two and assign each value to the correct field (?)

Comment: Maybe use a `fruit_color_and_fruit_type` virtual attribute, with some logic in the model, or the form object, to split it back into the real fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In the Controller

You could submit the combined values, then use logic in the controller to split them into the correct attributes. I think this way is cleaner and more reliable.

**app/models/fruit.rb**

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :fruit_color_and_fruit_type

  ...

end
```

**app/controllers/fruit_controller.rb**

```
class FruitController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    attrs = fruit_params
    attrs[ :fruit_color ] = attrs[ :fruit_color_and_fruit_type ].split( ' ' )[ 0 ].downcase(  )
    attrs[ :fruit_type ] = attrs[ :fruit_color_and_fruit_type ].split( ' ' )[ 1 ].downcase(  )
    @fruit = Fruit.new( attrs )

    if @fruit.save
      flash[ :success ] = 'New fruit created.'
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  ...

  private

    def fruit_params
      params.require( :fruit ).permit( 
        :fruit_color_and_fruit_type, 
        :is_rotten 
      )
    end
end
```

---

### In the Form

It is also possible to submit the information pre-formatted so you don't have to mess with it in the controller. Just use hidden inputs and a little JavaScript.

**app/models/fruit.rb**

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :fruit_color_and_fruit_type

  ...

end
```

**app/controllers/fruit_controller.rb**

```
class FruitController < ApplicationController

  ...

  private

    def fruit_params
      params.require( :fruit ).permit( 
        :fruit_color,
        :fruit_color_and_fruit_type, 
        :fruit_type,
        :is_rotten 
      )
    end
end
```

**app/views/fruit/new.html.haml**

```
%script
    :plain
        $( document ).ready( function (  ) {
            // the ids used here are the ones automatically assigned by form_for.
            $( document ).on( 'change', '#fruit_fruit_color_and_fruit_type', function (  ) {
                var value = $( this ).val(  );

                $( '#fruit_fruit_color' ).val( value.split( ' ' )[ 0 ].toLowerCase(  ) );
                $( '#fruit_fruit_type' ).val( value.split( ' ' )[ 1 ].toLowerCase(  ) );
            } );
        } );

= form_for @fruit do | f |
    = f.hidden_field :fruit_color
    = f.hidden_field :fruit_type
    = f.select :fruit_color_and_fruit_type, options_for_select(['Yellow apple', 'Red apple', 'Green apple', 'Yellow banana'])
    = f.check_box :is_rotten
    = f.submit 'Save!'
```